# How can I boot from an hard disk drive that has no primary partition?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I have a PC with 2 hard disk drives, every disk has its own Windows 10 installed. The problem is that just one of those disks have a boot partition to boot from (I used to boot from disk 1 to use Windows in disk 2), and turns out that the bootable disk just failed and now I can’t boot the other disk.

Is there a way to make the second disk bootable without reinstalling Windows? Maybe using the Windows installer?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/bcdboot

Comment: "primary partition" is a term from the 1980s ("MBR-based partition table"); while the matching partition table format is still formally supported by hardware, I **doubt** your Windows 10 boots from MBR (unless you manually forced your mainboard to "legacy mode", and installed windows afterwards). Are you *sure* this is the case here? I've talked to more than one person who was confused by the lack of "primary partitions" on a system with GPT – which simply doesn't know the concept of primary or secondary partitions (it's a stupid concept, to be honest).

Comment: No, it's not the case, I already edited the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To prepare the media that is required, you will need another
functioning Windows computer.

- Use a bootable partition editor to ensure that a few gigabytes of
  unallocated space exist on the disk, resizing some other partition
  if required. Some such are
  [Paragon Partition Manager Community Edition](https://www.paragon-software.com/free/pm-express/)
  or
  [GParted](https://gparted.org/).
- [Create Bootable USB Flash Drive](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2376-create-bootable-usb-flash-drive-install-windows-10-a.html)
- [Run a Startup Repair in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html)
- If this is not enough,
  [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: should they disconnect the bootable drive when doing this?

Comment: @Moab: As far as I understood, only one working drive is left.